# tikz - convert pdf to png line width not consistent

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to convert a pdf drawing to png, and would like if pdf drawing line width is 1, then converted png output is 1 pixel. for example:

```
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (1,1) -- (1,0) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If I use `convert -density 72 input.pdf output.png`, I got below output png (dimension is 31x31):

[image]

But if print the R value of each pixel in the png file, I got below output:

[image]

The right line is 1 pixel exactly, the bottom line used 2 pixel, and the diagonal line used 3 pixel.

I would like all lines output with 1 pixel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is related to antialiasing. Switch it off with `+antialias` (syntax might be confusing, but switching it on, which is default, would be `-antialias`):

```
convert -density 72 +antialias triangle.pdf triangle.png
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Great, that's what I want exactly! which software are you using to view image pixel by pixel? I use xviewer on linux but it seems not pixel by pixel.

Comment: @lucky1928 it is a coincidence rather, the converted png has a transparent background and my image editor (Kolourpaint) shows transparency as a checkerboard of grey and white single pixels.